# Custom ScrollView with the Floating info tag Connected to scrollBar

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to create something like a Scrollview in the Activity with Listview from list_0 to list_20.

Now when i touch and Scroll down i want to display a small tag near the scrollview indicating the row number and it should disappear after sometime.

Please help me i need this to be done in few hour 
thanks in advance [image]

Comment: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/01/17/starting-considering-android-as-a-capable-os/

Comment: Use the CustomList view , it is easy to get the click of each list in getview() of adapter class (extends the adapter class with BaseAdapter ).

Answer (score 0):

Get the that list item position and display that one in textview.
for eg., take two textview in horizontal mode this xml file add to the listview using layout inflater. first time the second textview take invisible state and when you click scrollview get the near list item position.create scrollview one id.